# How to define a method with Integer parameter (path placeholding)?

Tags: java, parameters, integer, method-signature

### Preface

I'd like to saying two things:

1. I don't know how to phrase this question in a few words. So I can't find what I'm looking for when searching (on stackoverflow). Essentially, I apologize if this is a duplicate.
2. I've only been programming Java consistently for a month or so. So I apologize if I asked an obvious question.

### Question

I would like to have a **method with a *parameter*** that holds **(path to) an *integer***.

How is such a method implemented in Java code?

### Restrictions

The *parameter* should be **generic**.
So, when there are **multiple** of that ***integer* variables**, the correct one can be used as argument to the method, when it is called (at runtime).

### My Idea as Pseudo-Code

Here's the idea of what I want (in pseudo-code). The idea basically consist of 3 parts:

- the method with parameter
- the variables holding integer values
- the calls of the method with concrete values

#### (A) Method

.
Following is the definition of my **method** named `hey` with ***generic* parameter** named `pathToAnyInteger` of type `genericPathToInt`:

```
class main {
    method hey(genericPathToInt pathToAnyInteger) {
        System.out.println(pathToAnyInteger);
    }
}
```

#### (B) Multiple Integer Variables

Following are the **multiple** *integer* variables (e.g. `A` and `B`; each holding an *integer*):

```
class A {
    myInt = 2;
}

class B {
    myInt = 8;
}
```

#### (C) Method-calls at runtime

Following is my main-method that gets executed when the program runs. So at runtime the (1) previously defined method `hey` is called using (2) each of the variables that are holding the different integer values:

```
class declare {
    main() {
        hey("hey " + A.myInt);
        hey("hey " + B.myInt);
   }
}
```

### Expected output

```
//output
hey 2
hey 8
```

### Personal Remark

Again, sorry if this is a duplicate, and sorry if this is a stupid question. If you need further clarification, I'd  be willing to help. Any help is appreciated. And hey, if you're going to be unkind (mostly insults, but implied tone too) in your answer, don't answer, even if you have the solution. Your help isn't wanted. Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "a path to an integer"?

Comment: I really don't wanna sound rude, but it isn't very clear what you're trying to achieve here. I would suggest referring to some basic tutorials first.

Comment: I suggested an edit to hopefully make your question more clear and expressed `path to an integer` and `generic parameter` in programming-related terms. What is the reason or task that brought you to ask the question?

Answer (score 0):

Integers in Java are primitive types, which are passed by value. So you don't really pass the "path" to the integer, you pass the actual value. Objects, on the other hand, are passed by reference.

Your pseudo-code would work in Java with a few modifications. The code assumes all classes are in the same package, otherwise you would need to make everything public (or another access modifier depending on the use case).

```
// First letter of a class name should be uppercase
class MainClass {
    // the method takes one parameter of type integer, who we will call inputInteger 
    // (method-scoped only)
    static void hey(int inputInteger) {
        System.out.println("hey " + inputInteger);
    }
}

class A {
    // instance variable
    int myInt = 2;
}
class B {
    // instance variable
    int myInt = 8;
}
class Declare {
    public static void main() {
        // Instantiate instances of A and B classes
        A aObject = new A();
        B bObject = new B();
        // call the static method
        MainClass.hey(aObject.myInt);
        MainClass.hey(bObject.myInt);
    }
}

//output
hey 2
hey 8
```

This code first defines the class MainClass, which contains your method **hey**. I made the method static in order to be able to just call it as `MainClass.hey()`. If it was not static, you would need to instantiate a MainClass object in the Declare class and then call the method on that object. For example:

```
...
MainClass mainClassObject = new MainClass();
mainClassObject.hey(aObject.myInt);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Java (since Java 8) contains elements of functional programing which allows for something similiar to what you are looking for. Your `hey` method could look like this:

```
void hey(Supplier<Integer> integerSupplier) {
     System.out.printl("Hey" + integerSupplier.get());
}
```

This method declares a parameter that can be "a method call that will return an Integer".

You can call this method and pass it a so called lambda expression, like this:

```
hey(() -> myObject.getInt());
```

Or, in some cases, you can use a so called method referrence like :

```
Hey(myObject::getInt)
```

In this case both would mean "call the hey method and when it needs an integer, call getInt to retrieve it". The lambda expression would also allow you to reference a field directly, but having fields exposed is considered a bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you need to use inheritance to achive what you are looking for.

let's start with creating a hierarchy:

```
class SuperInteger {
   int val;
   //additional attributes that you would need.

   public SuperInteger(int val) {
      this.val = val;
   }
   public void printValue() {
      System.out.println("The Value is :"+this.value);
   }
}  

class SubIntA extends SuperInteger {
    //this inherits "val" and you can add additional unique attributes/behavior to it 
   public SubIntA(int val) {
      super(val);
   }
   @override
   public void printValue() {
      System.out.println("A Value is :"+this.value);
   }
}

class SubIntB extends SuperInteger {
    //this inherits "val" and you can add additional unique attributes/behavior to it 
   public SubIntB(int val) {
      super(val);
   }
   @override
   public void printValue() {
      System.out.println("B Value is :"+this.value);
   }
}
```

Now you method Signature can be accepting and parameter of type SuperInteger and while calling the method, you can be passing SubIntA/SuperInteger/SubIntB because Java Implicitly Upcasts for you.

so:

```
public void testMethod(SuperInteger abc) {
     a.val = 3;
     a.printValue();
}
```

can be called from main using:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   testMethod(new SubIntA(0));
   testMethod(new SubIntB(1));
   testMethod(new SuperInteger(2));
}
```

getting an Output like:

```
A Value is :3
B Value is :3
The Value is :3
```